# with single how loop to print last 3rd element from given single linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

With single  loop how can we  print last 3rd element from given single linked list
lets take there are 10 node in give linked list and i am supposed to find last 3rd node?
below code is for inserting a node at beginning now how can i print last 3rd element with sing loop? please help me

```
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct *next; //hold address of next node
}

void insert_begin(struct node**ptr)
{  
    node *temp;
    temp=(struct *node) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cout<<"enter ur data"<<endl;
    cin>>temp->data;
    temp->next=*ptr;
    *ptr=temp;
}

int main()
{
    node *head=0 // making head node or 1st node null
    insert_begin(&head);
    insert_begin(&head);
    insert_begin(&head);
    .....upto 10
}
```

Comment: If you have the count of the linked list then it should be easy. Else I'm not quite sure.

Comment: maybe you could just always track the last 3rd elem from your current elem while iterating (and begin with index nr. 3 so you don't have to handle the special case at start) - probably as a pointer; as soon as you reach the end of the list, the 3rd last elem of the currently iterated elem becomes the 3rd last elem of the list.

Comment: "last third element" - that means the element third from the end of the list? Or you want to print the last third of the *entire* list (a list of 10 elements would be printing the last 3 elements, rounding down. A list of 30 elements would print the last 10 elements, etc.) ? The vernacular is a little rugged, so an **example** of a list you have, and what you expect, along with what you have *tried*, would be helpful. And unrelated, this: `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` has little reason to be in a C++ program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep three pointers:

```
node * prevPrev = null;
node * prev = null;
node * current = head;
```

Iterate over the list with `current` until `current->next` is null.
At each iteration, update `prev` and `prevPrev`

```
prevPrev = prev;
prev = current;
current = current->next;
```

When `current->next` is null, `prevPrev` points to the last 3rd element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two pointers *p1,*p2 and initialize them so that *p1 points to the first element and *p2 points to the third element of your list. Then loop until *p2 reaches the end of your list, moving both pointers to the next element in each loop. When *p2 reaches the end print the element pointed by *p1.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to do this in easy way what you can do is first manage counter variable for length of link i.e. 'count'. now:

```
int len = count;
*temp = ptr;

while(tmp->next != null)
{
    len--;
    if(len==3)
    { 
        //you are at the last third element
        // do your work and break the loop
    }
    else
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```